# Multipe Stacked Divs with horizontal and vertical centering

Tags: html, css

I've looked for hours on how to do this and have tried numerous experiments which get me some, but not all of the features I need on my landing page.  Once I get the final piece of the puzzle in place, it seems to break other pieces I already have working.  So it seems I can solve the problem in pieces, but I fail when I try to combine the pieces.  Perhaps there's a conflict between them that can't be resolved?  I'm pretty sure this is something that can be accomplished.

Let me attempt to explain what I'm trying to do:

I need two divs that sit side-by-side on my landing page when it's in a wide format (wider than 320px), but I want the two divs to stack on top of each other when the web page is not wide (< 320px).  This is easy enough to accomplish by using: style="display:inline-block;float:left;" on each div and the two behave as I want.  However, this breaks down when I try for other needed features, such as:

1. The contents of the left div (which is also the top div when 'stacked' due to a narrow browser window) need to be centered both horizontally and vertically within that left div in both the wide (>320px) and narrow (<320px) page formats.
2. The contents of the right div will be fixed at 320px wide and 420px high in both page formats as I'm using a facebook plugin to post status updates.
3. The left div size should scale dynamically with the browser window size as follows:
4. When the page width is > 320px, I want the left div to be the same height as the right div (420px) so that the contents in the left div will be centered vertically with respect to the contents of the right div.
5. When the page width is < 320px, I want the left div (which is now stacked on top) to only be 50px high, and the right div (now stacked on bottom) to remain fixed at 420px high.
6. The contents of the left div should always stay horizontally and vertically centered within that div no matter the width or height of the left div.

Can it be done with pure .css, or is a javascript hack necessary?

Hopefully I've explained it well enough that someone can help me out - it would be greatly appreciated and will allow me to move on with coding the rest of the page.

Thanks

Comment: When you say "contents of right div will be fixed" in feature #2, are you trying to fix the contents within the div, but not the div itself? So the div will change in side but won't be smaller than `320px420px`?

Comment: The right div will be a fixed size (320px wide by 420px high), as it's for a facebook plugin.  Ideally both divs stay centered (as a group) on the page until the page width decreases, at which point the left div stacks on top of the right one.  The contents of the left div should always stay centered horizontally and vertically within that left div.  The left div can have a minimum width (say, 100px) but should resize horizontally and vertically as the page size is changed.  Does that help?